Reclaim an already claimed before PersistentVolume
We have a an SMB container storage interface driver running in our cluster to access CIFS shares.
The 'smb' storage class is installed with provisioner: smb.csi.k8s.io and the PersistentVolume points to the storage class.
Then create a Deployment with this volume and CIFS shares are accessed.
But after deleting the deployment the PVC is removed and the PV status becomes released.
And when creating the deployment again it cannot reclaim the PV again until the PV is deleted and recreated or as what is said in What to do with Released persistent volume? to put the claimRef on null. But I don't see a way to do this automatically every time with kubectl patch pv -p {claimref: null}
Is there really no way to have a PVC reclaim an already claimed before PV when a new deployment asks for it?
Then other deployments can retake the PV again and again. With CIFS shares we're not really creating anything, we'jre just connecting pods to an existing "filesystem" so claiming volumes does not make sense really.
Also I want to have multiple deployment claiming the CIFS shares for all kinds of purposes where new ones claim old ones automatically.
     containers:
       - image: busybox
         volumeMounts:
           - name: smb
             mountPath: "/mnt/smb"
      volumes:
        - name: smb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-smb

